# Is the isomorphism problem solvable for Euclidean groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose you had two group presentations, and you know they are Euclidean groups, can you tell if they are isomorphic or not?

It has been suggested to me that it is probably possible to tell if they are isomorphic, but I can’t find a proof or come up with one myself.

Edit:
Apologies for the confusion over what i mean by a Euclidean group. By Euclidean groups I mean discrete cocompact subgroups of isometries of euclidean space (of any dimension). This definition comes from 'Word Processing in Groups' by David B. A. Epstein et al, p.87.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Euclidean group?" Do you mean a discrete isometry group of a Euclidean space?

Comment: @MoisheKohan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group

Comment: Your link does not clarify your post. According to the linked definition, Euclidean groups cannot be finitely or recursively presented.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I must be misunderstanding something. How come they have solvable word and conjugacy problem?

Comment: Who are "they?"

Comment: @MoisheKohan How come Euclidean groups have solvable word and conjugacy problem? See listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups in the examples Euclidean groups have solvable word problem. They are also proven to be biautomatic in the book 'word processing in groups 1992' (section 4.2. Euclidean Groups are Biautomatic). I must be misunderstanding what you mean by they, apologies if it is obvious.

Comment: This is a good example of why you should not use Wikipedia as your only source.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Looking at the book 'Word Processing in Groups' by David B. A. Epstein, in section 4.2 it is shown Euclidean groups are biautomatic, and biautomatic groups have solvable conjugacy problem (page 59), which also implies solvable word problem. Are you saying this is not correct?

Comment: You are managing to conflate two different notions: "a Euclidean group" (a group of cardinality of continuum understood as in your first Wikipedia link) and "finitely generated virtually abelian group" (all your other references). See my first comment under your post. If, as you insist, a "Euclidean group" is understood in the sense of the first link, then they cannot be biautomatic, etc. Of course, Epstein et al, say nothing of this sort.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for clarifying. So if I am understanding you correctly,  there are two different definitions of what it means to be a Euclidean group?

Comment: Yes. Personally, I prefer to avoid this terminology altogether exactly for this reason. In your question, these should be understood as discrete isometry groups of finite dimensional Euclidean spaces, aka Bieberbach groups, equivalently, finitely generated virtually abelian groups.

Comment: With this in mind, if you edit your question, I might even write a sketch of an algorithm for the isomorphism problem. Maybe Derek knows a reference.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have now edited the post with the definition from 'Word Processing in Groups' as you stated. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Another thing: You are actually asking about decidability of the "uniform isomorphism problem" for the class of Euclidean groups (probably with a given upper bound on the virtual abelian rank). But this is just small nitpicking.

Comment: To solve the isomorphism problem I guess you could identify the finitely many maximal normal free abelian subgroups in each group, identify their finite quotients and actions on the free abelian group and then use cohomology calculations to compare the extension classes. But I don't have the energy to check the details right now!